# Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration version via NuGet?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, castle-windsor, nuget

Added Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration via NuGet, and now when I try to run the site, I get the following error:

> Method 'get_IsOpen' in type
>   'Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.StatelessSessionDelegate'
>   from assembly
>   'Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration,
>   Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' does
>   not have an implementation.
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.TypeLoadException: Method
>   'get_IsOpen' in type
>   'Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.StatelessSessionDelegate'
>   from assembly
>   'Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration,
>   Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' does
>   not have an implementation.

Latest Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration version available via NuGet is 1.1.0

Other package versions added via NuGet:

- Castle.Core: 2.5.2
- Castle.Windsor: 2.5.3
- NHibernate: 3.1.0.4000
- NHibernate.Castle: 3.1.0.4000
- FluentNHibernate: 1.2.0.712
- Castle.Core-log4net: 2.5.2
- Castle.Windsor-log4net: 2.5.2
- Rx-Core: 1.0.2856.0
- Rx-Main: 1.0.2856.0
- Rx-Interactive: 1.0.2856.0
- Castle.Services.Transaction: 3.0.6.1006

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your version of NHibernateIntegration to the latest version (currently 1.1.0.39).  Your current version, 1.1.0.0, is not compatible with NHibernate 3.1 and above.  NHibernate 3.0.0.4000 didn't have the IsOpen property that's being complained about

Comment: Why isn't this version on nuget?

Answer (score 0):

Check the dependencies of the other packages - it sounds like you might have brought in two packages that reference different versions of `Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration` (eg. maybe one is using something later than 1.1, which has the Open property?)